# Which is better way of injecting service to controller with __construct or $instance = parent::create($container)

Tags: 9, services, dependency-injection

I'm always using this way of injecting service to controller:

```
<?php    
namespace Drupal\TestModule\Controller;
    
    use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
    
    class TestModuleController extends ControllerBase {
    
      protected $testModule;
    
        public function __construct(TestModule $testModule) {
        $this->testModule = $testModule;
      }
    
      public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
        return new static(
          $container->get('testModule.service')
        );
      }
    
      public function testModule() {
        return [
          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => $this->testModule->getTestModule(),
        ];
      }
    }
```

But with drupal console I generate Controller with service (drupal gcon command) and get different code:

```
<?php
    namespace Drupal\TestModule\Controller;
    
    use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
    use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
    
    class TestModuleController extends ControllerBase {
    
      protected $testModule;
    
      public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
        $instance = parent::create($container);
        $instance->testModule = $container->get('testModule.service');
        return $instance;
      }
    
      public function testModule() {
        return [
          '#type' => 'markup',
          '#markup' => $this->testModule->getTestModule(),
        ];
      }
    }
```

Is this second way better than first and which should I use?

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR: The second way is better.

The constructor method `__construct()` is considered internal, you can not *(savely)* overwrite it. E.g. the number or type of mandatory function parameters might change. Therefore the first version's code might break even within a minor update of Drupal core. Only the second version is guaranteed to work at least until the next major version release.

For more information I'd suggest reading this [Change record from the Webform module](https://www.drupal.org/node/3076421).

Comment: Ah yeah, the CR is nice. I had this issue bookmarked: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3067546

Comment: Here also an interesting read on this [Safely extending Drupal 8 plugin classes without fear of constructor changes](https://www.previousnext.com.au/blog/safely-extending-drupal-8-plugin-classes-without-fear-of-constructor-changes)